Swagger: Required @OA\PathItem() not found issue with Laravel 10
I'm encountering an issue when trying to regenerate the documentation used php artisan l5-swagger:generate in my Laravel project. The command results in the following error:
Regenerating docs default

   ErrorException 

  Required @OA\PathItem() not found

  at vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php:31
     27▕         } else {
     28▕             $error_level = E_USER_WARNING;
     29▕         }
     30▕ 
  ➜  31▕         trigger_error($message, $error_level);
     32▕     }
     33▕ }
     34▕ 

      +21 vendor frames 

  22  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

Here are some relevant details from my project:
composer.json:
"php": "^8.1",
"darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.6",
"doctrine/annotations": "^2.0",
"doctrine/dbal": "^3.8",
"filament/filament": "^3.2",
"filament/notifications": "^3.2",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"laravel/framework": "^10.10",
"laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.27",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.4",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^2.1"

app/Http/Controller/Controller.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    /**
     * @OA\Server(
     *    url=L5_SWAGGER_CONST_HOST,
     *    description="API Documents"
     * ),
     * @OA\Info(
     *    title="Crazy Job API",
     *    version="1.0.0",
     * )
     */
}

app/Swagger/Controller/V1/App.php:
<?php
/**
 * @OA\Get(path="/app/info",
 *   tags={"App"},
 *   summary="App Info",
 *   description="get app info",
 *   operationId="app",
 *   @OA\Response(
 *      response=200,
 *      description="Response Success",
 *      @OA\JsonContent(
 *         @OA\Property(
 *              property="data",
 *              ref="#/components/schemas/AppInfo"
 *         )
 *      )
 *   ),
 * )
 */

app/Swagger/Models/AppInfo.php:
<?php

/**
 * @OA\Schema(
 *     schema="AppInfo",
 *     @OA\Property(
 *         property="id",
 *         type="string",
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Property(
 *         property="domain",
 *         type="string",
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Property(
 *         property="key",
 *         type="string",
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Property(
 *         property="status",
 *         type="boolean",
 *     ),
 */

Despite having these annotations, I still get the "Required @OA\PathItem() not found" error. Can anyone provide guidance on what might be causing this and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!
I'm encountering an issue when trying to regenerate the documentation using php artisan l5-swagger:generate in my Laravel project. The command results in the following error:
Regenerating docs default

   ErrorException 

  Required @OA\PathItem() not found

  at vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php:31
     27▕         } else {
     28▕             $error_level = E_USER_WARNING;
     29▕         }
     30▕ 
  ➜  31▕         trigger_error($message, $error_level);
     32▕     }
     33▕ }
     34▕ 

      +21 vendor frames 

  22  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
